# What is the probability that you will draw 7 vowel tiles from a scrabble bag with all tiles?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

[image: Table of Information]

There are 100 tiles in total and there are 42 tiles that are vowels. If the question is asking me the probability of drawing 7 vowel tiles with all tiles, would this be 42% since 42/100 is 42%? Or, would the numbers change each time I pull out a vowel?

Comment: Have you figured out how many tiles have vowels on them?  how many tiles there are in total?

Comment: How could it possibly be true that the probability of drawing seven vowels is the same as the probability of drawing one vowel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly:

$$N_{vowels}=N_A+N_E+N_I+N_O+N_U=9+12+9+8+4=42$$

The total number of letters is:

$$1\times 5+2\times 10+3\times 1+4 \times 4+ 6 \times 3+8 \times 1 + 9 \times 2+12 \times 1=100$$

This means that since the number of vowel and the number of total letters decreases when I draw a tile:

$$p=\frac{42\times 41 \times... \times 36}{100\times 99 \times ... \times 94}=\frac{59163}{35104300}\approx 0,1685 \% $$

:)

Comment: Would the numerator of the fraction not go to 35 instead of 36 since I'm drawing out 7 tiles? Likewise with the denominator, would it not be 93?

Comment: @E.Morris This is a classic mistake, notice that $\{36,...,42\}$ has $7$ elements and not $6$. In  general $\{a,...,b\}$ with $b>a$ has $b-a+1$ elements :)

Comment: Thank you so much :)